# Does STAB increments damage of type attacks?

Tags: pokemon-series

Let's use Charizard as an example. It is 4x weak to Rock type attacks (2x Flying + 2x Fire). If Onyx uses Rock Slide on a Charizard, will the attack be 6x? (4x + 50% STAB)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

As you can see from the [Damage Formula](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Damage#Damage_formula):

[image]

where *Modifier* is:

[image]

- *STAB* is the same-type attack bonus. This is equal to 1.5 if the attack is of the same type as the user, and 1 if otherwise.
- *Type* is the type effectiveness. This can be either 0, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, or 4 depending on the type of attack and the type of the defending Pokémon.
- *Critical* is 2 for a critical hit in Generations I-V, 1.5 for a critical hit in Generation VI, and 1 otherwise.
- *other* counts for things like held items, Abilities, field advantages, and whether the battle is a Double Battle or Triple Battle or not.
- *random* is a random number from 0.85 to 1.00.

You can see that *Type effectiveness* and *STAB* are both applied to the final damage.

Comment: Solid formula you've got there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, STAB applies on top of any other damage modifications, multiplicatively. In this case, Charizard will take 6x damage.